# Alfresco Version and Tagging

Tags: java, alfresco

Is it possible to tag the particular version of the file in Alfresco ? If so kindly guide me how to achieve it. Any kind help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here/s the javascript API documentation: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/3.4_JavaScript_API#Versions_API

Otherwise, in Java use VersionService bean: http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/docs/java/repository/org/alfresco/service/cmr/version/VersionService.html

If you dont know which version exactly you want you can go trough version history array in JavaScript or in Java use "getVersionHistory" method of VersionService then on VersionHistory you use "getAllVersions" which is plain old java Collection (java.util.Collection).

Hope that helps. :)

Comment: I tried. But I cannot add tag to the version. I can only add tag to the current working copy.

Comment: That might not be the versioning problem. Maybe that is the way it works. Im not sure about this though...

Answer (score 0):

You can use **getVersionHistory** method of **VersionService** to return **VersionHistory** object. From this object you are able to get every version of node. **Version** object represents single version of node. Calling method **getVersionedNodeRef** of **Version** object you are getting NodeRef of that version of node. Finally, use **TaggingService** and method **addTag** to add tag to nodeRef of node version.
I hope this will help you.